# Find sql tables that got transacted in workflow OR Extract table from V$sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

If i run a front end workflow how do i find which tables got transacted for (select insert delete or update)?
I am using Oracle 11g, Is there a way how to extract the table names from sql_text of V$sql OR v$sqlarea

Comment: What you're describing sounds like auditing. You most likely won't find what you're looking for in V$SQL; there's no guarantee it will have any info that _isn't_ real-time. Even SQL from a few seconds ago could get aged out if your database is busy. Auditing captures as much detail as you could want, and is historical by design.

Comment: So is it not possible to find the latest DML(select, update, insert) transacted

Comment: V$ tables only show you what is true in real time, in that instant. They can give you insight to things that are in the library cache, but that gets overwritten as new SQL gets executed, so there's no _guarantee_ what's going to be in it 5 seconds later, or that you'll see things like the value of bind variables. If you want history of transactions, bind variables, and other metadata, then you either have to mine the actual transaction logs (which won't include select statements), or use auditing, which catches everything you configure it for.

Comment: Thanks, From where do i get the logs or auditing data. How do i query them

Comment: Start by reading this for 11g, and seriously consider an upgrade to a supported version, if possible: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000